# Google Sheets Query() function returns unexpected character error

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, parse-error

I am trying to create a list of rows in a larger table that are missing data. to do this I wrote

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:J361,"Select A:E, I where J is null")
```

to retrieve rows without data in column J. This returned the error

```
 Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
 PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <UNEXPECTED_CHAR> ": "" at line 1, column 9.
```

sample data:

```
|Lab # |Site|Block|Plot|Rep |Treatment| Lower Depth|Upper Depth|Depth (cm)  |Sample bag wet (g)|
|:-----|:---|:----|:---|:---|:--------|:-----------|:----------|:-----------|:-----------------|
3100|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|1|Compost + Biochar|    0|  10| 0-10|   622.17|
3101|SFREC/WLIC|    1|  1|  1|  Compost + Biochar   |10 |20 |10-15| 157.58
3102|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|1|Compost + Biochar|20|30|20-30|    
3103|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|2|Compost + Biochar|0|10|0-10|430.18
3105|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|2|Compost + Biochar|20|30|20-30|
```

expected result:

```
|Lab # |Site|Block|Plot|Rep |Depth (cm)|    
|:-----|:---|:----|:---|:---|:--------|
3102|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|1|20-30|    
3105|SFREC/WLIC|1|1|2|20-30|
```

Comment: For some reason stack overflow refuses to let me format the sample data as a table, instead insisting that it is improperly formatted code.

Comment: The error tells you. You can't use `:` in the query. Use `A, B, C, D, E` instead. Or build the string dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As General Grievance suggests, you can't use a range of cells in the query. Instead, you must name each column you wish to use. For example, the following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:J361,"Select A,B,C,D,E,I where J is null")
```

Alternatively, if you wanted it to be easier to expand the range of columns you are selecting, you could avoid the use of the `=QUERY` function entirely and use `=FILTER` instead. Here is an example that produces the same results as the query above:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:E361,Sheet1!I2:I361},Sheet1!J2:J361="")
```